# Redshift percentile_disc query and group by

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table that looks like this (containing the number of times a particular user has visited a particular page)

```
n  | context_page_path | user_id
--------------------------------
10 | /some/path/       | 1
23 | /some/path/       | 2
30 | /some/other/p/    | 1
...
```

I'm trying to get the 75% percentile of visits to each page like so:

```
select 
    context_page_path,
    percentile_disc(0.75) within group (order by n) over (partition by context_page_path) as percentile_75
from my_table
group by context_page_path
```

However, when I run this query, Redshift wants me to include `n` in the `group by` clause.

I'm not sure why it's asking for this?

If I want the average, I can do that easily like so with no complaints.

```
select 
    context_page_path,
    avg(n)
from my_table
group by context_page_path
```

Answer (score 1):

`percentile_disc()` is a window function, rather than an aggregation function.  So, you can use:

```
select distinct context_page_path,
       percentile_disc(0.75) within group (order by n) over (partition by context_page_path) as percentile_75
from my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the Window Function syntax instead of the Aggregate Function syntax. Try this:

```
select 
    context_page_path,
    approximate percentile_disc(0.75) within group (order by n) as percentile_75
from my_table
group by context_page_path
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_APPROXIMATE_PERCENTILE_DISC.html

It's a bit confusing but the two functions are in two different sections of the docs.